# What is the significance of `_flag` in FILE struct?

Tags: c, file, struct

I am working in an industry code, where, for some workflow, the `FILE*` is getting corrupt. I looked into the struct member values and found that `_flag` had been assigned seemingly high value of ~33000.
This made me conclude that it had gone corrupt.

Now, I am not sure as to how to proceed further. May be knowing the significance of `_flag` might help?

Comment: The internals of the structure referred to by a `FILE*` are implementation defined. Before chasing that rabbit down an endless hole, use a debugger and/or a tool like valgrind to sanity check your program.

Comment: How did you determine that your `FILE` is corrupt?

Comment: *found that _flag had been assigned seemingly high value of ~33000. This made me conclude that it had gone corrupt.* You came to that conclusion without determining what valid values could be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can't say for sure, because the internals of a `FILE` struct are implementation-dependent, but the `_flag` field is generally a bitmask which the stdio package uses to keep track of various options which have been set (read, write, line-buffered, etc.), and various other bits of state concerning the stream, such as whether it's hit EOF.

For example, on the system where I'm typing this, `<stdio.h>` defines these values for its own flags field:

```
#define __SLBF  0x0001          /* line buffered */
#define __SNBF  0x0002          /* unbuffered */
#define __SRD   0x0004          /* OK to read */
#define __SWR   0x0008          /* OK to write */
#define __SRW   0x0010          /* open for reading & writing */
#define __SEOF  0x0020          /* found EOF */
#define __SERR  0x0040          /* found error */
#define __SMBF  0x0080          /* _buf is from malloc */
#define __SAPP  0x0100          /* fdopen()ed in append mode */
#define __SSTR  0x0200          /* this is an sprintf/snprintf string */
#define __SOPT  0x0400          /* do fseek() optimisation */
#define __SNPT  0x0800          /* do not do fseek() optimisation */
#define __SOFF  0x1000          /* set iff _offset is in fact correct */
#define __SMOD  0x2000          /* true => fgetln modified _p text */
#define __SALC  0x4000          /* allocate string space dynamically */
#define __SIGN  0x8000          /* ignore this file in _fwalk */
```

So if the `__SWR`, `__SEOF`, `__SERR`, `__SMBF`, and `__SIGN` bits were set, the flags value would be 33000.  (That's a pretty meaningless combination of flags, but you get the idea.)

Bottom line, values such as you saw are to be expected, and would not by themselves suggest that the `FILE` structure has been corrupted.